# How to set mark shape for a regression plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make a regression line from my data and add a legend to the drawing. The mark shape is OK in the legend, but wrong on the regression line. What do I wrong?

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}               
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
    \definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0,0,.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
        legend style={
            cells={anchor=west},
            legend pos={south east},
        },
        xmin=0, xmax=51,% x scale
        ymode=log,
        ymin=5e-8, ymax=2e-5, % y scale
scatter/classes={%
    MPP={mark=diamond*,draw=webgreen},Cluster={mark=triangle*,draw=webblue}, MPPR={mark=diamond,draw=webgreen},ClusterR={mark=triangle,draw=webblue}}]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[meta=label] {
x y label
3   9.656E-07   MPP
4   1.096E-07   MPP
6   2.191E-07   MPP
45  1.052E-06   MPP
49  4.131E-06   MPP
50  4.682E-06   MPP
    };
    \addlegendentry{MPP data in 2016}

\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[meta=label] {
x y label
2   1.991E-07   Cluster
5   1.040E-07   Cluster
11  1.225E-06   Cluster
31  1.365E-05   Cluster
33  2.677E-06   Cluster
34  1.718E-06   Cluster
38  1.243E-06   Cluster
39  4.628E-06   Cluster
    };
    \addlegendentry{C data in 2016}

\addplot table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}, mark=diamond,
 meta=label,    /pgf/number format/read comma as period
]
{
x Y label
3   9.656E-07   MPPR
4   1.096E-07   MPPR
6   2.191E-07   MPPR
45  1.052E-06   MPPR
49  4.131E-06   MPPR
50  4.682E-06   MPPR
    };
    \addlegendentry{Regression of MPP in 2016}

\addplot table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}, mark=triangle,
 meta=label,    /pgf/number format/read comma as period
]
 {
x Y label
2   1.991E-07   ClusterR
5   1.040E-07   ClusterR
11  1.225E-06   ClusterR
33  2.677E-06   ClusterR
34  1.718E-06   ClusterR
38  1.243E-06   ClusterR
39  4.628E-06   ClusterR
    };
    \addlegendentry{Regression in 2016}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mark=diamond` have to be set as option for `\addplot`:

```
\addplot+[mark=diamond] table[...]{...};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}               
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}% loads also pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- set a compat; current version is 1.15
    \definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
    \definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0,0,.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
        legend style={
            cells={anchor=west},
            legend pos={south east},
        },
        xmin=0, xmax=51,% x scale
        ymode=log,
        ymin=5e-8, ymax=2e-5, % y scale
scatter/classes={%
    MPP={mark=diamond*,draw=webgreen},Cluster={mark=triangle*,draw=webblue}, MPPR={mark=diamond,draw=webgreen},ClusterR={mark=triangle,draw=webblue}}]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[meta=label] {
x y label
3   9.656E-07   MPP
4   1.096E-07   MPP
6   2.191E-07   MPP
45  1.052E-06   MPP
49  4.131E-06   MPP
50  4.682E-06   MPP
    };
    \addlegendentry{MPP data in 2016}

\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[meta=label] {
x y label
2   1.991E-07   Cluster
5   1.040E-07   Cluster
11  1.225E-06   Cluster
31  1.365E-05   Cluster
33  2.677E-06   Cluster
34  1.718E-06   Cluster
38  1.243E-06   Cluster
39  4.628E-06   Cluster
    };
    \addlegendentry{C data in 2016}

\addplot+[mark=diamond]table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},
 meta=label,    /pgf/number format/read comma as period
]
{
x Y label
3   9.656E-07   MPPR
4   1.096E-07   MPPR
6   2.191E-07   MPPR
45  1.052E-06   MPPR
49  4.131E-06   MPPR
50  4.682E-06   MPPR
    };
    \addlegendentry{Regression of MPP in 2016}

\addplot+[mark=triangle] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},
 meta=label,    /pgf/number format/read comma as period
]
 {
x Y label
2   1.991E-07   ClusterR
5   1.040E-07   ClusterR
11  1.225E-06   ClusterR
33  2.677E-06   ClusterR
34  1.718E-06   ClusterR
38  1.243E-06   ClusterR
39  4.628E-06   ClusterR
    };
    \addlegendentry{Regression in 2016}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```